# iterate through array with foreach php

Tags: php, foreach, linkedin-api

Any idea how to access creator with foreach? I receive this as a result from the linkedin groups API and want to iterate through it, after joining the first level with foreach($data as $value) - I am not sure how to iterate through the second and third array to access the values for creator

```
Array
(
[_total] => 4
[values] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [creator] => Array
                    (
                        [firstName] => Martin
                        [headline] => test1
                        [id] => DNz_ycOHn5
                        [lastName] => asdf
                        [pictureUrl] => https://media.licdn.com
                    )

                [summary] => hi summary
                [title] => hi title
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [creator] => Array
                    (
                        [firstName] => Martin
                        [headline] => test2
                        [id] => DNz_ycOHn5
                        [lastName] => asdf
                        [pictureUrl] => https://media.licdn.com
                    )

                [summary] => summary
                [title] => testpost
            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [creator] => Array
                    (
                        [firstName] => Martin
                        [headline] => test3
                        [id] => DNz_ycOHn5
                        [lastName] => asdf
                        [pictureUrl] => https://media.licdn.com
                    )

                [summary] => 12312
                [title] => linkedinDEV
            )

        [3] => Array
            (
                [creator] => Array
                    (
                        [firstName] => Martin
                        [headline] => test4
                        [id] => DNz_ycOHn5
                        [lastName] => asdf
                        [pictureUrl] => https://media.licdn.com
                    )

                [summary] => test123
                [title] => Discussion Title
            )

    )

  )
```

best

M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 5.5, you can use in this case [array_column](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php):

```
$creators =  array_column($data['values'],'creator');
```

Answer (score 1):

This will create an array of creators:

```
$creators = array();

foreach($data['values'] as $value) {
    $creators[] = $value['creator'];
}

// An array containing the creator information
var_dump($creators);
```